# fill pandas column based on another column's index

Tags: python, pandas

so I have a dataframe that is called leads and it contains a column called "id" and it contains 98% null values.

and I have another dataframe and it contains a column called lead_id.

both dataframe are not the same length.

how can I fill the null values from the first dataframe column ( that contains 98% empty values ) with the values from the leads_id? but wherever there is a value in the "id" column, I wanna leave it there and not replace it.

I tried to concat both dataframes but it does not work because the values that are already inside the 'id' column will be overwritten

leads:

```
    timestamp   id
0   15/09/2021 8:50 NaN
1   15/09/2021 9:27 NaN
2   15/09/2021 8:50 NaN
3   15/09/2021 8:50 NaN
4   15/09/2021 8:50 NaN
... ... ...
291195  01/10/2021 0:05 NaN
291196  01/10/2021 0:05 NaN
291197  01/10/2021 0:05 NaN
291198  NaN NaN
291199  01/10/2021 0:05 NaN
```

target:

```
    lead_id converted_to_tenant
0   345291  0
1   308962  0
2   308962  0
3   306085  0
4   309542  0
... ... ...
266041  298696  0
266042  321010  0
266043  321010  0
266044  339470  0
266045  247094  0
```

Comment: please post samples of your both dataframes so we can reproduce,  something like this: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})

Comment: There is an issue, there is nothing in common bewteen the two DataFrames or am i mistaken? how we can tell which id belongs to which row?

Comment: How are these dataframes connected? How do you know which lead_id is linked to an id?  i.e. is there another column (e.g. name) that can be used to match the lead_id to the correct id?

Comment: @stevp the leads dataframe contains loads of other columns but they are irrelavant to what i am trying to do. the idea is that the first one has data about people and the second one just has the id of those people and if they converted into tenants or not. so what I want to do is to fill the missing values of the id column in the leads dataframe with the values of the lead_id column in the target dataframe without removing the already existent values in the id column

Comment: Since you mentioned the dataframes are not the same size, how can you tell the leads_id - id correspondence? For example, in your example code, which row of the leads dataframe should the leads_id in row 0 (345291) fill? Row 0, 1, 2, 3...? Row 0 of target dataframe should fill row 0 of leads dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same size this works i think :

```
leads.id.fillna(target.lead_id, inplace=True)
```

Comment: they are not the same size they are different sizes

Comment: @mouhamad then we need more details i think, what link the two dataframes together ? how do you know which id can be replaced by lead_id